# iOS - How to check wheather pem file is valid or not?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have created development and production pem files. I have followed this steps:

1) developer.apple.com : AppIDs section check Bundle id supports Development SSL Certificate
if no then create that certificate (which supports APNS)

2) open key chain

3) right click on our certificate and export certificate.

4) you will get .p12 file from here : like : hope_APNS.p12

5) open console(terminal) and run following command (use created .p12 file here as input)
openssl pkcs12 -in apns-dev-cert.p12 -out apns-dev-cert.pem -nodes -clcerts

6) you will get .pem file for the same. (like hope_APNS.pem)

Developement pem file is working fine. But there is some in production pem file. When i set production pem file and send push notification from console. I won't get push on my device.

Comment: there is no any way to test pem file if want to  test.just only way sending the pushnotifiction while getting response and check error try to solve

Comment: have you follow all the steps properly then there is no any mistake happen for refer all step from that answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250510/generate-pem-file-used-to-setup-apple-push-notification

Comment: for developement the push token is different compared to Production.Are u using the same token?

Comment: @muku i have used different token, I know push token for dev and production is different.

Comment: @Nimit Parekh i have followed this steps. In my case dev pem file is working perfectly. but in production pem file, it will create some issue. It is possible to check whether pem file is correct or not through commands on terminal. I have checked it on terminal also.

Answer (score 35):

That's an old thread but I was looking for the same answer and hope this solution help someone... worked for me.

You can test your PEM key using the following command, which should hang if successful until you press enter:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert pnpush.pem -key pnpush.pem
```

The above tests the PEM Key in sandbox mode. For production mode, use the following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert pnpush.pem -key pnpush.pem
```

Thanks to Craig at https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/234/how-do-i-test-my-pem-key

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why you may not be getting push notifications via a production .pem certificate on your device. Besides making sure you generated the distinct production certificate correctly, here are few things to check:

1. You have an Ad-Hoc or Distribution build running on your test device
   when testing a production certificate
2. You have successfully
   collected the production push token of said device (which will
   always be different from the development push token)
3. You are able to connect to Apple Push Notification PRODUCTION servers
   (gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195) with the new certificate (ie/
   you're able to open a socket connection and it does not close
   immediately)
4. You have checked that your certificate is not expired

Failing all that, you really need to check what is going on at the network level when you send something via that certificate. If it's invalid, it won't connect at all to Apple. If it's valid but the push token you're sending is not recognized by Apple, an error code will be returned (if you are using the binary interface) or the connection will be severed. You may also want to look into the [APNS Feedback API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3) to gain more insight on what is going wrong.

You may want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196145/apn-php-code-giving-warning-stream-socket-client-function-stream-socket-clie/15203324#15203324) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446705/meaning-of-different-status-codes-in-apns-error-response-packets/15302663#15302663) other answer for more tips.

Comment: I have revoke production pem file and created new one. It solved my issue.